# Help me show that matrix S is orthogonal if and only if $(Sx)\cdot (Sy)=x \cdot y$ for $x,y\in R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**I have a problem with the part (b) of the following question**

**Question**

In the following question we regard vectors in $R^n$ as columns and define the dot product in the usual way which means that $x \cdot y=x^ty$

a) If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix show that $A_{ij}=\mathbf{e}_i \cdot A\mathbf{e}_{j}$ where $\mathbf{e}_i , i= 1, . . . , n$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

**b)** Show that matrix S is orthogonal if and only if $(Sx)\cdot (Sy)=x \cdot y$ for $x,y\in R^n$

---

**My Approach**

a) Let $e_{ik}$ and $e_{jk}$ represent the kth element of $e_i$ and $e_j$ respectively. We know that $e_{ik} = 0 \;\forall i \neq k, = 1\textrm{ otherwise}$. Same is true for $e_{jk}$.

Now, $(Ae_j)_k$ denote the kth element of $Ae_j$. Hence, $(Ae_j)_k = \sum_{m = 1}^n A_{km}e_{jk} = A_{kj}$

That is, $Ae_j$ results in the jth column of A.

Thus, $$e_i^{\top}Ae_{j} = \sum_{k = 1}^n e_{ik}(Ae_{j})_k = (Ae_{j})_k = A_{ij}$$

**b)** This is the part that I don't know. How do I show this?

Comment: What definition of "orthogonal" are you using? Some books might say that the thing you're trying to show actually *is* the definition of "orthogonal".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Deduce from a) that square matrices $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $x^TAy=x^TBy$ for all vectors $x,y$.

Then use this for $x^TIy=x^Ty=x\cdot y =(Sx)\cdot(Sy)=x^TS^TSy$.

Answer (score 0):

By (bi)linearity, you simply have to prove $S$ is orthogonal if and only if $\;Se_i\cdot Se_j=\delta_{ij}$.

Now  $S$ is orthogonal if and only if $\;^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}S S=I$. This translates as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n S_{ki}S_{kj}=\delta_{ij}$$
Just observe $\;Se_i=\bigl(S_{ki}\bigr)_{1\le k\le n}$,  $\;Se_j=\bigl(S_{kj}\bigr)_{1\le k\le n}$ and you're done.